# Retrieve #anchor in url

Tags: url

Is it possible to get the #id anchor in the URL?

EG: https:www.domain.co.uk/page#anchor

I see url helper has something called {fragment} but It doesnt output anything?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with the anchor? EE doesn't acknowledge hashes but be interested in why you need this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I know this is possible with JavaScript location.hash but I don't think EE segment tags or php can do it easily if at all.

Please reference the location hash documentation here. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp